# Почему PHP 7.3 отругляет числовые значения при выполнении json_encode?

Tags: php, json, json-encode, округление

Выполняю на PHP 7.3.23 следующий код:

```
$x = new stdClass;
$x->price = 33.4;
var_dump($x);//object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["price"]=> float(33.4) }
echo json_encode($x);//{"price":33.399999999999999}
```

Если выполнить в PHP 5.3 строку echo json_encode($x); то результат будет {"price":33.4}
А так же округления не будет если присвоить свойству строковое значение, например: $x->price = "33.4";

Хотелось бы понять, что за ситуация, почему в новых версиях PHP разработчики решили реализовать такое округление и в особенности есть ли какая либо настройка, с использованием которой можно было бы избежать указанного округления для версии PHP 7.3

---

Добавляю уже после того как нашёл ответ: округления в json_encode числовых значений в PHP 7.3 видимо быть не должно. Предполагаю что у меня такая ситуация произошла в результате обновления версии PHP с более ранней, то есть значение serialize_precision в php.ini у меня осталось от более ранней версии(то-есть равное 17), что в версии PHP 7.3 и привело к описанному результату. Детали в комментариях к вопросу.

Comment: Сейчас у себя проверил — всё нормально от 7.3 до 8.1...

Comment: Вот пример выполнения https://blog.ivru.net/10-11/writeJson.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981409/php7-1-json-encode-float-issue

Comment: Алексей, благодарю, вот эта строчка помогла: ini_set('serialize_precision',14);

Comment: `serialize_precision` выставьте на -1 в `php.ini`. 17 - устаревшее значение, которое использовалось до 7.1.

Comment: А значение 14 которое я использовал и которое указано по ссылке, оно чем отличается?

Comment: Есть предположение что значение 17 в PHP ini появилось у меня в результате когда то обновлённого PHP с 7.0 или 7.1 до 7.3. То есть значение видимо осталось от старой версии.